WD Elements 1TB External hard drive with Ubuntu 24.04 is not getting mounted
Newbie here. Currently my PC was showing a booting error so i made a bootable usb and opened ubuntu 24.04 on my PC. I started taking a backup of my data on the WD Elements 1TB external harddisk. The first time it worked but i unfortunately disconnected the hardisk as the device got stuck on the tranfer screen. I tried to reconnect it again and i was getting this mounting error. The odd thing is, it is showing me to format the harddisk when i connect it to a phone or another Laptop. Will i need to format the HDD as my data will be lost and i don't have any other backup apart from this and since my device is not recognising my internal hdd, i tried this plan.
. Please help me get out of this situation. Thanks :'( [Error message ][1]
Edit: I moved the data instead of copying it. So if i cannot recover the data myself, will data recovery services be able to do that for me?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/v8gfJAeo.jpg

I was able to get the data off after using a real windows chkdsk however, the drive wasn't right until I reformatted it.

@vidarlo did supply a decent answer before the question was closed.  Currently I've changed to using Ext4 format for my 1TB external drives. Fortunately I haven't had a 'cable jiggle' since but if I do, the word is fsck should have more success correcting the ext4 drive than even a real windows system would correcting it if formatted NTFS.

@user68186, actually i moved the data instead of copying it. What can i do in this situation?
